# Вероятность события

Tags: алгоритм, логика

Добрый вечер. Хотелось бы обсудить следующий вопрос: 
Допустим имеются две команды (футбольные, хоккейные и тд, не принципиально) - А и В. 
Предположим, обе команды имеют свой рейтинг, определяющий их силу. Команда А имеет рейтинг rA, а команда В - rB. Матч между этими командами может закончиться одним из нескольких результатов. Предположим, что возможных результатов 5 - ничья, победа команды А, уверенная победа команды А, победа В, уверенная победа В. Собственно, вопрос: как для каждого  из пяти результатов сформировать вероятность того, что данное событие случится? Для простоты предположим, что на результат влияет только соотношение рейтингов команд, без учета каких-либо других факторов. Следует также учесть, что вероятность уверенной победы какой-либо из команд обычно (за исключением случаев с  большой разницей в рейтинге) значительно ниже, чем вероятность обычной победы.
 Из-за довольно поверхностных (да что уж там, практически нулевых) знаний в теории вероятности на ум приходят только совершенно дуболомные варианты решения описанной проблемы.

Comment: Хм, а какой вероятностный смысл рейтинга?

Comment: @VladD видимо если у команды больше рейтинга, то значит и больше шанс победить. Вот и нужно составить вероятность, так сказать, "с перевешиванием".

Comment: да, именно - чем больше рейтинг, тем больше вероятность победить. То есть рейтинг - это "сила" команды

Comment: @lampa: ну это конечно хорошо, но какой смысл самого числа? ТС ведь хочет получить численную вероятность? Покамест, если все рейтинги увеличить на 100 или взять их экспоненту, соотношение "больше/меньше" не сменится. Если рейтинг команды А вдвое возрос, значит ли это, что вероятность победить любую другую команду В тоже возросла вдвое? (И если да, как он считается?) Без ответов на такие вопросы понятие рейтинга не имеет смысла.

Comment: @DreamChild, Это вопрос на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: я это понял, пожалуй, только в процессе данного обсуждения)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы взял обыкновенное нормальное распределение и поделил бы его на несколько зон:

- вершина кривой - ничья
- середина спада - победа/поражение
- ноль - "уверенная" победа/поражение

Из двух рейтингов возьмем наибольший *rMax*, а разность рейтингов *rA - rB* обозначим за *rDelta*. Тогда можно получить коэффициент *k = rDelta / rMax*.

Теперь, используя полученный коэффициент, можно сдвинуть вершину кривой нормального распределения влево/вправо в зависимости от его знака (если положительный, значит сдвиг в сторону команды A, отрицательный - в сторону команды B). Простое линейное масштабирование по оси Х, если рассматривать кривую в системе координат XY.

Comment: Не учел, что в условии только полная победа/поражение должно иметь пониженную вероятность. В моей модели при равных рейтингах наиболее вероятным исходом будет ничья.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала обратимся в рейтинг и посмотрим, какие места занимают наши команды. Формула такова:

```
(|команда А - команда B|) / (кол-во команд в рейтинге - 1)
```

Для решения задачи придумаем конкретные числа: 6 команд, 2 и 3 место

```
 (|2-3|) / (6-1) = |-1| / 5 = 1 /5 = 0.2
```

Теперь построим численный ряд:

```
2 - Ув. победа A
1 - Победа A
0 - Ничья 
-1 - Победа B
-2 - Ув. победа B
```

Вероятность какого либо события - 20%, вероятность любой победы A - 40%.

Чтобы у A была больше вероятность, нам придётся приминусовать к каждому элементу шкалы 0.2

Теперь получается вот-так:

```
2 - 0.2 - Ув. победа А
1 - 0.2 - Победа А
0 - 0.2 - Ничья
-1 - 0.2 - Победа B
-2 - 0.2 - Ув. победа B
```

Что же это означает - а то что вероятность любой победы A = 40% + 0.2/1 = 40% + 5% = 45%. Вероятность уверенной - 25%, обычной - 20%

Тоже самое, но с другими числами:

```
(|1-8|) / (8 - 1) = 1
1
0
-1
-2
-3
```

Тогда: 1) ув. поб. B не будет, так как числа генерируются от 2 до -2. 2) Вероятность любой победы A 60 % , вероятность ув. победы А 40%, а обычной - 20%. Ничья - 20%.

Comment: извините, а с чего вы взяли, что вероятности наступления событий одинаковы и равны 0.20? Они будут равны только в случае, если команды равны по силам. Вопрос как раз и состоит в том, чтобы вычислить эти вероятности в зависимости от того, каково соотношение рейтингов.

Comment: @DreamChild А что там с рейтингом? Я так понял, что та команда, которая выше получает +0.20

Comment: рейтинг дается изначально. Задача в том, чтобы сформировать вероятности наступления всех пяти событий, исходя из соотношения рейтингов. Допустим, команда А имеет рейтинг 100, а команда В имеет рейтинг 20. Рассуждая логически можно предположить, что команда А, имея значительно более высокий рейтинг, имеет и значительно более высокие шансы как на победу, так и на уверенную победу. А если,скажем, у команды А рейтинг равен 50, а у команды В - 40, то это (опять же исходя из логики вещей) значит, что более вероятна победа А или ничья. Так вот для всего этого нужен алгоритм, или формула расчета.

Answer (score -1):

А давайте порассуждаем.

Пусть будут внесены переменные:

- А1 - ничья
- А2 - победа в пользу первой команды
- А3 - победа в пользу второй команды

При одинаковом рейтинге вероятность будет 1 к 3 (А1 = А2 = А3 = 1/3).

Пусть:

- АР1 - рейтинг первой команды (например 20)
- АР2 - рейтинг второй команды (например 30)

Теперь воспользуемся такой формулой:

```
// статическая вероятность для обоих команд
А = А1*АР1 + А2*АР2 = 1/3*20 + 1/3*30 = 16,(6)

// вероятность для команды 1
Аа1 =А1*АР1 / А = 1/3*20/16,(6) = 0,4016064257028112
// вероятность для команды 2
Аа2 =А2*АР2 / А = 1/3*30/16,(6) = 0,6024096385542169
```

Становится ясно, что АР2 имеет 60% вероятности победы, а AP1 - 40% вероятности победы.

Теперь внесем вероятность ничьи путем математической операции между процентными соотношениями команд о_О

`(100% - бОльшее значение)/2` - и будет процентом ничьи (т.е. чем больше перевес команды, тем меньше процент ничьи).

Получается:

```
// статическая вероятность для обоих команд
А = А1*АР1 + А2*АР2;

// вероятность для команды 1
Аа1 =А1*АР1 / А;
// вероятность для команды 2
Аа2 =А2*АР2 / А;

// процент ничьи
N = (1 - Аа1 > Аа2 ? Аа1 : Аа2)/2;

// процент выигрыша первой команды
Аа1 -= N/2;
// процент выигрыша второй команды команды
Аа2 -= N/2;
```

Хреново или будет работать?

Comment: Всю писанину до внесения вероятности ничьи можно было выразить куда короче:

Аа1 = AP1/(AP1+AP2) // 1, если в знаменателе ноль

Aa2 = 1-Aa1

Comment: @Flammable не писанина, а математические выражения :D Я писал ведь сразу, не думая о том, как будет короче.

Comment: @lampa, по-моему как раз короткий вариант понятней.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение:

    А (победа одной из команд) = К1 * !К2 + !К1 * К2 = 0.4 * (1 - 0.6) + (1 - 0.4) * 0.6 = 0.52
    
    B (ничья) = !К1 * !К2 = (1 - 0.4) * (1 - 0.6) = 0.24

Comment: @Flammable если у вас из под руки сразу выходит такое выражение, то поздравляю. У меня другой профиль деятельности :)